# Angular not showing interpolated value in html

Tags: javascript, angular, spring-boot

I am using spring boot + angular.

Interpolation is not working for me. Whenever I reload the page I can see the changes in spring boot console but {{product.productId}} is not printing anything in the HTML page.

search.component.html

```
  <div class="form- group col-md-4 offset-4 mt-4 card card-body">
  <form >
    <input type="text" name="search" [(ngModel)] ="search" placeholder="enter the products">
  </form>
</div>

<div *ngFor="let products of products | filter:search" >
     {{products.productId}}
</div>
```

search.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ProductService } from '../product.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-search',
  templateUrl: './search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search.component.css']
})
export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {
  products;
  search:string;

  constructor(private service: ProductService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
        this.service.getAllProducts().subscribe(data=>{
        this.products = data ['products'];
      });

  }
}
```

product.service.ts (Service method)

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProductService {
  private httpUrl = "http://localhost:8080/products"
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getAllProducts(){
    return this.http.get (`${this.httpUrl}`);
  }

}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { SearchComponent } from './search/search.component';
import { AddProductComponent } from './add-product/add-product.component';
import { FilterPipe } from './filter.pipe';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ProductService } from './product.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    SearchComponent,
    AddProductComponent,
    FilterPipe
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [ProductService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

filter.pipe.ts

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'filter'
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(products,search:string):any  {
    if(search){
      return products.filter(product=>{
         return product.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
      });
    }else{
      return products;
    }
 }
}
```

I want to display products in search.component.html, everytime I reload the page I can see changes in backend(spring boot terminal) but it is not printing in html page through interpolation.

Comment: Have you checked, that the filter pipe works correctly? My guess would be that it doesnt.

Comment: Yes...filter pipe is not working, that interpolation issue is solved.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div *ngFor="let product of products | filter:search" >
     {{product.productId}}
</div>
```

Change this line.It will work for you.When u are iterating the names should be different.

Comment: Im pretty sure what suggestion which I gave it has to work. Maybe there is a problem in your filter pipe.Can you add your filterPipe code as well.